# How doe's the Java Graphics2d Fill method work?

Tags: java, graphics, 2d

Can anybody tell me what algorithms or methods the java graphics2D fill uses, or how it works?

or if you can point to the source code(I don't know if that is even possible).

Thanks

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can access the documentation for any java classes/methods at:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/

if you navigate to graphics2d (under All Classes, on the left), it should have an explanation of the class and of all its methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can't "see" it, because its usually implemented in hardware of a graphics card---take a look at http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/2d/new_features.html#ogl.